# Facebook iOS FBLoginView buttons do not appear - requires scrolling in LoginView

Tags: ios, facebook, scroll, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

We're using the Facebook iOS SDK. By default we get obscured Login buttons at the bottom (see screenshot) - the user has to scroll down manually to see/touch them.

How can we ensure the user doesn't have to scroll to see them?

We're using Facebook SDK 3.18

[image: Obscured facebook login buttons.]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, we're looking into this.